# Moq setup to return some hardcoded POCO

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to adopt this link to get some objects inside moq to pass to my service. http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2014/01/creating-unit-test-using-moq-to-stub.html

I'm getting on error on the Returns() function saying there isn't an overloaded function that meets this. All, returns an IQueryable object.

```
Mock<IGroupsRepository> groupRepo;

groupRepo.Setup(m => m.All).Returns(new List<GROUPS>()
                {
                    new GROUPS { ID = 0, GROUP_NAME = "TEST1", CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now, CREATED_BY = "Joe Blow", DESCRIPTION = "Test1" },
                    new GROUPS { ID = 1, GROUP_NAME = "TEST2", CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now, CREATED_BY = "Joe Blow", DESCRIPTION = "Test2" }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All, returns an IQueryable object.

`List<GROUPS>` does not implement `IQueryable<T>`, so `All` could never return such a list.

You can call [`AsQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the list to get a `IQueryable<T>` representation of the list though.

```
var queryable = new List<GROUPS>()
                {
                    new GROUPS { ID = 0, GROUP_NAME = "TEST1", CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now, CREATED_BY = "Joe Blow", DESCRIPTION = "Test1" },
                    new GROUPS { ID = 1, GROUP_NAME = "TEST2", CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now, CREATED_BY = "Joe Blow", DESCRIPTION = "Test2" }
                }.AsQueryable();


groupRepo.Setup(m => m.All).Returns(queryable);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new List<GROUPS>()
                {
                    new GROUPS { ID = 0, GROUP_NAME = "TEST1", CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now, CREATED_BY = "Joe Blow", DESCRIPTION = "Test1" },
                    new GROUPS { ID = 1, GROUP_NAME = "TEST2", CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now, CREATED_BY = "Joe Blow", DESCRIPTION = "Test2" }
                }
        .AsQueryable()
```

`AsQueryable()` should make it compatible with `IQueryable` return type